# How to download a file and new html page in the same response

Tags: asp.net, http

I have an asp.net web site and on a particular page the user can download a binary file after clicking a button. This works fine but I want a new HTML page to be served after the button is clicked, not just the file. Can this be done with multiple content sections in the HTTP response? Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done anyway - HTTP doesn't allow for this.

What you're probably thinking of are sites that offer links that actually go to other pages, then the page has a client-side redirection (e.g. `<meta http-equiv="refresh" />`) to the actual resource to download the file.

Like so:

#### Download index page:

```
<a href="/downloads/widget/245">Download Widget v2.4.5 now!</a>
```

#### /downloads/widget/245

```
<html><head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="/widget245.exe" />
</head><body>
    <p>Please wait while your download begins. The prompt should appear immediately.</p>
</body></html>
```